# Can Spring Cloud Gateway work with microservices that are not asynchronous?

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, microservices, synchronous, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a few synchronous microservices working on production using Spring Boot 2.X version. Soon, we need to implement a gateway if the number of instances of each microservice is going to be increased. I read that Zuul was in a maintenance phase and was replaced by Spring Cloud Gateway which is by default asynchronous technology. My question is, can I still implement Spring Cloud Gateway with my microservices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Spring Cloud Gateway` without any doubts.

Basically, `asynchronous technology` means that your resources/threads on `Api Gateway` won't be blocked waiting for the response from downstream services and that increases a throughput.

Now, once your blocking services complete their internal logic they respond back to `Api Gateway` using an originally opened connection. `Api Gateway` in turn responds back to your client.

Comment: I appreciate your answer @StepanTsybulski. It has really helped me understand the situation.